# "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component." Only when functional component is a Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-hooks, inertiajs

I'm getting the following warning on my application with Laravel + InertiaJS + React:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

I'm doing the example available at the documentation of InertiaJS: https://inertiajs.com/forms

I'm making the use of the "useForm" helper of inertiaJs, looking into the code it has following event on the "post" function:

```
onSuccess: (page) => {
          if (isMounted.current) {
            setProcessing(false)
            setProgress(null)
            setErrors({})
            setHasErrors(false)
            setWasSuccessful(true)
            setRecentlySuccessful(true)
            recentlySuccessfulTimeoutId.current = setTimeout(() => setRecentlySuccessful(false), 2000)
          }

          if (options.onSuccess) {
            return options.onSuccess(page)
          }
        },
```

The warning occurs when the setTimeout function is invoke to setRecentlySuccessful(false) after 2000ms.

But the warning **only happens when I put the form component inside a separate Functional Component** to be reusable and more readable on the component that renders the Page.
When I use the same form as my Top tree component, it does not trigger the warning.

I'm still learning to use ReactJS, so i don't know if it's ok to make a functional component of my entire form so it can be reusable on the application.
Also, how much of a problem is the warning itself.

**CODE**
Pages/Login.js

```
import LoginComponent from '@/Components/LoginComponent';

function Login() {
    return (
        <article>
            <LoginComponent />
        </article>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

LoginComponent

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

function LoginComponent() {
    const { data, setData, post, processing, errors } = useForm({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        remember: false,
    });

    function submit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        post('/login');
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={data.email}
                onChange={(e) => setData('email', e.target.value)}
            />
            {errors.email && <div>{errors.email}</div>}
            <input
                type="password"
                value={data.password}
                onChange={(e) => setData('password', e.target.value)}
            />
            {errors.password && <div>{errors.password}</div>}
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={data.remember}
                onChange={(e) => setData('remember', e.target.checked)}
            />{' '}
            Remember Me
            <button type="submit" disabled={processing}>
                Login
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

Comment: Just making sure I understand: You see this warning if you use `<Login />` but not if you use `<LoginComponent />` directly?

Comment: Yes. If I put the content of the <LoginComponent /> on the <Login /> directly, it does not give me the warning.